# I cannot figure out whats wrong with the onClickListener function of button here in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

**I want to click on a button in my fragment 2 , and replace fragment 1 with fragment 3 as shown in the code.
But the findViewById(r.id.mybutton) is returing 'null' .
I tried debugging the code but its not able to use the created 'buttontoggle'
 Hope you can help me out with the above problem 
Thanks in advance :)

```
    package com.vivekmishra1991.testfrag;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            return;
        }

               //fragment 1

        f1 F1= new f1();
        F1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, F1).commit();
                   //fragment2(the fragment with the button)

        f2 F2=new f2();
        F2.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container1, F2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }



     //code for buttton onclick function
    Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {  // fragment 3 that has to be replaced with fragment 1
            f3 F3=new f3();
            F3.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,F3).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my activityMain.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"   >

<FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="6"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

## f2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Next!"
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have a Button with id "mybutton" defined in `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: nothing wrong with your syntax. seems like it's a problem with your xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your .xml file to make sure that "mybutton" does exist.

If so, try Project > Clean. Occasionally, eclipse doesn't add the button to the R.java file, and cleaning the project tends to fix that. If its not that either, you can always try to recreate the button in your xml file.